# Is there a blazor way of simulating a click event on an html element?

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have two elements, an InputFile and a button. And I want to simulate a click on InputFile upon clicking the button. I have it working with Js now but would like to know if there's a blazor way of doing it.
[An example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JscAu.gif)

and this is the current blazor code

```
<InputFile id="filePicker" />
<button type="button" @onclick="OpenFilePicker">or Select</button>

private async Task OpenFilePicker() => await JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("clickElement");
```

and with this Js code I can make it work though,

```
clickElement = () => document.getElementById('filePicker').click();
```

Is there a better solution without Js dependency ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to trigger a click event from blazor without using javascript.

You can use the ref directive to get a reference to an element from blazor but you'll still need javascrit to trigger the click on the element.

```html
<InputFile @ref="filePicker"></InputFile>
<button type="button" @onclick="() => click()">Select a file</button>

<script>
    window.triggerClick = (elt) => elt.click();
</script>
```

```cs
@code {
    InputFile filePicker;
    async Task click() {
        await js.InvokeAsync<object>("triggerClick", filePicker.Element);
    }
}
```

But since you're trying to trigger a click on an input there's a pure html way to do it using a label

```html
<InputFile id="filePicker"></InputFile>

<label for="filePicker">
    <button type="button" style="pointer-events: none;">Select a file</button>
</label>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. This helped me at least remove the Js dependency.